# importing a go project from a private gilab repo using ssh: unknown revision

Tags: go, gitlab, go-modules

I am trying to import a go project from a private and self hosted gitlab repo using ssh. When i try to do so, i get the following error.

output

```
kbacon@kbacons-MacBook-Pro bbz % go get -x gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools@latest
# get https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools?go-get=1
# get https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools?go-get=1: 200 OK (0.413s)
mkdir -p /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs # git3 https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools.git
# lock /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179.lock# /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179 for git3 https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools.git
cd /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179; git tag -l
0.013s # cd /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179; git tag -l
cd /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179; git ls-remote -q origin
0.020s # cd /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179; git ls-remote -q origin
# get https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools.git
# get https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools.git: 200 OK (0.186s)
go: gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools@v1.0.0: reading gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools/go.mod at revision v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
```

.gitconfig

```
[user]
        name = kbacon
        email = kbacon@email.com
[url "git@gitlab.wtf.notworking/"]
        insteadof = https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/
```

go mod file

```
module bbz
go 1.14
require (
    gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools v1.0.0
)
```

gitlab repo

the gitlab repo has a project with a release tag `v1.0.0`

The address i use to clone

```
ssh://git@gitlab.wtf.notworking:2224/bbq/tools.git
```

ssh config file

```
Host gitlab.wtf.notworking
    User kbacon@email.com
    Hostname gitlab.wtf.notworking
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company_gitlab # path to private key
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

---

With this .gitconfig:
.gitconfig

```
[user]
        name = kbacon
        email = kbacon@email.com
[url "git@gitlab.wtf.notworking:2224/"]
        insteadof = https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/
```

The `go get` command then requests my password, but it is supposed to be using ssh. Why is it asking for my password?

```
kbacon@kbacons-MacBook-Pro bbz % go get -x gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools@latest
# get https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools?go-get=1
# get https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools?go-get=1: 200 OK (0.424s)
mkdir -p /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs # git3 https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools.git
# lock /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179.lock# /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179 for git3 https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools.git
cd /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179; git tag -l
0.030s # cd /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179; git tag -l
cd /Users/kbacon/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3bd57e1dd1ed847c1ac192f16c5f67541135ce037a175de23ec5fb5051d10179; git ls-remote -q origin
git@gitlab.wtf.notworking's password:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an SSH URL with `/` instead of `:`, your `.gitconfig` should be:

```
[url "ssh://git@gitlab.wtf.notworking:2224/"]
        insteadof = https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/
```

With ":"

```
[url "git@gitlab.wtf.notworking:2224:"]
        insteadof = https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/
```

In your ssh config file, make sure to use the service account `git`, not your login, with the port, and a custom Host entry:

```
Host gitlab-wtf
    User git
    Hostname gitlab.wtf.notworking
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company_gitlab # path to private key
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    Port 2224
```

That way, you can use:

```
[url "ssh://gitlab-wtf/"]
        insteadof = https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/
```

No more `git@` or `:2224`.

Comment: I tried `[url "git@gitlab.wtf.notworking:2224:"]insteadof = https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/`. It is still requesting a password.

Comment: i added my ssh config file, incase it helps.

Comment: @prolink007 Try the `ssh://git@gitlab.wtf.notworking:2224/` syntax instead. And check first that an ssh -Tv `ssh://git@gitlab.wtf.notworking:2224` is working (meaning it opens an SSH session, interactive or not depending on the server). If it works from the command line, make sure your go process is using the same user environment.

Comment: @prolink007 I have spotted some possible issue in your SSH config file. See my edited answer.

Comment: if i change my gitconfig to `[url "git@gitlab.wtf.notworking/"] insteadof = https://gitlab.wtf.notworking/` and i ONLY add the port to my ssh host config, it no longer asks for a password. BUT it then says `go: gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools@v1.0.0: reading gitlab.wtf.notworking/bbq/tools/go.mod at revision v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0`

That repo has a tag `v1.0.0`.

Comment: That worked. I forgot the `ssh://` in front of what you suggested. Thanks, what a nightmare.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like port number is missing in .gitconfig

UPD: I see if you add it you get a different error, but clearly port number IS needed as you're running ssh on non-standard port.

Comment: i added a new section to my question that shows what happens with the port. It asks for a password but i am requesting to use ssh. Why does it need my password? I would assume it would not need it.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but worth trying to run `go env -w GOSUMDB=off` to disable go mod proxy

Comment: i added my ssh config file, incase it helps.